# ¿Cómo abrir un PDF en Python usando solo una cadena de bytes o Base64? (Sin utilizar directorios)

Tags: python, pdf, base64

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente código en Python que me imprime el número de páginas y los datos de un PDF, sin embargo, esto solo funciona si llamo al PDF con un directorio de mi PC. Lo que quiero que haga es que me abra el PDF usando solo la cadena de Bytes o Base64 que le proporciono **sin tener que escribir un nuevo PDF en mi pc**.

````
PDFBase64="JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1..."
Decodificado=base64.b64decode(PDFBase64)
documento=fitz.open(Decodificado)

print("Número de páginas: ",documento.page_count)
print("Datos: ",documento.metadata)```
````

Comment: Según la doc, el formato es `open(filename)`, donde  *filename must be a Python string (or a pathlib.Path) specifying the name of an existing file.* O sea, tiene que ser un archivo en disco (ni siquiera un stream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentación en la que me basé: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document

Para decirle a pymupdf que queremos cargar el archivo desde la memoria, usamos el argumento stream, cuya documentación traducida por mi y el traductor de google dice:

> **stream (bytes, bytearray, BytesIO)**: un área de memoria que contiene un
> documento admitido. Si no es un PDF, su tipo debe especificarse
> mediante filename o filetype.

Que, como podemos ver, acepta objetos de tipo byte. Ni siquiera necesitamos un stream.

Este código de ejemplo, cargamos un pdf de internet (en forma de bytes) y lo guardamos en el disco, demostrando así que el contenido fue recuperado correctamente (requiere la librería requests)

```
import requests
import fitz

pdf_url = "https://serviciosweb.afip.gob.ar/genericos/formularios/pdf/interactivos/f460f.pdf"

pdfbytes = requests.get(pdf_url).content

fitz.open(stream=pdfbytes).save("prueba.pdf")
```

---

Nota final: A veces, la documentación responde nuestras dudas. Siempre es buena idea revisarla antes de preguntarle a otro. Podrías encontrar la respuesta mucho más rapida y autonomamente. Para darte una idea de lo util que es, yo nunca usé este modulo y pude darte una respuesta c:

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, enserio llevaba días buscando una solución para esto y me salvaste ;)

Comment: De nada FistBro c: